# Django : Type Mismatch Error in models.py

Tags: python, django

When I execulte these lines in `python3 manage.py shell` :

```
In [1]: from dream_site.models import Mentor, Mentee, Team
In [2]: a = Mentee.objects.get( pk = 1 ).name
In [3]: b = Mentor.objects.get(pk=1).name
In [4]: print( a + b )
```

It prints the proper output as expected, however in the `models.py` when I have the following code it gives me the `int() argument must be a string or a number` error :

```
def __str__(self):     # Belonging to Team object
    return ( str( self.pk ) + " - " +  Mentor.objects.get( pk = self.mentor_id ).name   + " - " +  Mentee.objects.get( pk = self.mentee_id ).name   )
```

This is the place where the error is occurring. Even though it shows these as `str` types in the shell.

Other parts of the `models.py` :

```
class Mentor(models.Model):
    mentor_id =     models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    name =          models.CharField( default = '', max_length = 254 )

class Mentee(models.Model):
    mentee_id =     models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    name =          models.CharField( default = '', max_length = 254 )

class Team(models.Model):
    team_id =                       models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    mentor_id =                     models.ForeignKey( Mentor )
    mentee_id =                     models.ForeignKey( Mentee )
    team_since =                    models.DateTimeField( default = django.utils.timezone.now, blank = True )
```

Comment: of which class is `__str__(self)` part of?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that it was in the Team object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've confused yourself by using the wrong naming convention.

In Team, `mentor_id` and `mentee_id` are *not* IDs. They are are the actual `Mentor` and `Mentee` objects. So in your `__str__` method, where you try and query the Mentee class using the value of `mentee_id`, you're actually passing an existing Mentee object to the query. There's no need to do that.

Your fields should be called `mentor` and `mentee`, and you should use them directly in your method:

```
return str(self.pk) + " - " +  self.mentor.name   + " - " +  self.mentee.name
```

or even better, use string interpolation:

```
return "%s - %s - %s" %  (self.pk, self.mentor.name, self.mentee.name)
```

Comment: Daniel, it would have to be self.mentor_id and self.mentee_id (since they were named that way) it would have been best oif they were named without the _id since in the db, the '_id' is added by django when the tables are created

Answer (score 2):

`mentor_id`, `mentee_id` are not integers in `Team` class. They are of `Mentor` and `Mentee` type respectively. Use instead:

```
 self.mentor_id.name
```

and

```
 self.mentee_id.name
```

in `__str__`.

Of course it's even better to rename these fields to `mentor` and `mentee` in the `Team` class.

Comment: Thank you ! Don't know why you got downvoted randomly though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a foreign key, you can access it's table elements directly. Also, use `format`, it does the type conversion on your behalf.

```
def __str__(self):     # Belonging to Team object
    return "{0} - {1} - {2}".format(self.pk, self.mentor_id.name, self.mentee_id.name)
```

For more details on formatting, check out [PyFormat](http://pyformat.info)

Answer (score 1):

You should just reference them as objects...

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id =                       models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    mentor_id =                     models.ForeignKey( Mentor )
    mentee_id =                     models.ForeignKey( Mentee )
    team_since =                    models.DateTimeField( default = django.utils.timezone.now, blank = True )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.team_id, self.mentor_id.name, self.mentee_id.name)
```

Django provides you with an ORM wrapper, which means, you can build your classes and especially the connection between your classes, without caring about database storage or implementation. 
You can easily assume, that your `Team` objects have a direct link to their corresponding `Mentor` and `Mentee` objects.
You should not care about database id's in Django code.

So, even better (clearer) would be this:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.AutoField( primary_key = True )
    mentor = models.ForeignKey( Mentor )
    mentee = models.ForeignKey( Mentee )
    team_since = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, blank=True )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(self.team_id, self.mentor.name, self.mentee.name)
```